# I have a table and I need time difference between two events using SQL Query

Tags: sql, database

Here's the table that I have,

| Number | Status | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2132 | Group Joined | August 22, 2022, 2:54 PM |
| 3299 | Group Joined | August 12, 2022, 9:24 PM |
| 3299 | Group Left | August 23, 2022, 5:43 PM |
| 2132 | Group Left | August 30, 2022, 5:32 PM |
| 2132 | Group Joined | September 3, 2022, 2:23 PM |

and I need time difference between `Group Joined` and `Group Left` of same `Number` and the `Time` column in the table is in bona fide datetime format.

And I only need the phone numbers whose time period is `More than 12 hours`.

I have tried using `DATEDIFF` but I am somehow not able to get the output I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `DATEDIFF()` along with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Number
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Number
HAVING DATEDIFF(hour,
                MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Group Joined' THEN Time END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Group Left'   THEN Time END)) > 12;
```

Here the max of `CASE` expressions find the times for group joined and group left.